# How to compile code to ASM file using dcc32/dcc64?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

How can I compile code with Delphi directly to ASM file without using the IDE (ALT + CTRL + D). Something like this can be done with Visual C++ `cl.exe /Fa[assembler code filename]`.

Or if that cannot be done can I atleast at bare minimum disassemble it with some meaningful debug information. If so how?

Comment: Consider generating obj file instead. Then convert it to COFF32 using objconv. Then link it.

Answer (score 4):

Delphi does not support compilation to assembler. It can output object code, but not assembler.

If you want to disassemble code, there are many disassemblers in existence that can be found with a websearch. Questions asking for tool recommendations are off topic here so that part of your question is, strictly, off topic